# spacy Entity Ruler pattern isn't working for ent_type

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

I am trying to get the entity ruler patterns to use a combination of lemma & ent_type to generate a tag for the phrase "landed (or land) in Baltimore(location)". It seems to be working with the Matcher, but not the entity ruler I created. I set the override ents to True, so not really sure why this isn't working. It is most likely a user error, I am just not sure what it is. Below is the code example. From the output, you can see that the pattern rule was added after NER and I have set the override ents to true. Any input or suggestions would be appreciated!

The matcher tags the entire phrase (landed in Baltimore), but the entity rule does not.

**Code Sample**

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern = [{"LEMMA":"land"},{}, {"ENT_TYPE":"GPE"}]
patterns = [{"label":"FLYING","pattern":[{"LEMMA":"land"},{}, {"ENT_TYPE":"GPE"}]}]

matcher.add("Flying", [pattern])

rulerActions= EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True)
rulerActions = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler","ruleActions").add_patterns(patterns)
# rulerActions.add_patterns(patterns)

print(f'spaCy Pipelines: {nlp.pipe_names}')

doc = nlp("The student landed in Baltimore for the holidays.")

matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print(f'{string_id}  ->  {span.text}')
    
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

**Print Statements**

```
spaCy Pipelines: ['tok2vec', 'tagger', 'parser', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer', 'ner', 'ruleActions']
Flying  ->  landed in Baltimore
Baltimore GPE
the holidays DATE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working version of your code:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

patterns = [{"label":"FLYING","pattern":[{"LEMMA":"land"},{}, {"ENT_TYPE":"GPE"}]}]

ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler","ruleActions", config={"overwrite_ents": True})
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)

print(f'spaCy Pipelines: {nlp.pipe_names}')

doc = nlp("The student landed in Baltimore for the holidays.")

matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print(f'{string_id}  ->  {span.text}')
    
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

The Matcher you are creating isn't used at all. When you call `EntityRuler` that creates an EntityRuler, but calling `add_pipe` creates a completely different object, and it doesn't have the `overwrite_ents` config.

Comment: Oh duh. Thanks for the help @polm23! I did not see that. Thanks!

Comment: I came here following the demo on spacy.io; although their in-browser code worked, I had to run your code instead. 
 https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler